# need to loop the json string

Tags: c#

using the azure graph api to get the group members .i got the response in the following format:

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "",
  "value": [
    {
      "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/5-93e1d09bdf66/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/cb18b0aa-0ac6f51/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/cf11211a06-ddee967505d8/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/6a-bb9d-f08aee852c96/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/62fce837ffb/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/787cc75e-4726-89d/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/26a2789b-2d/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/6efcc6f2-333b-41e-6/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User"
    }
  ]
}
```

but not able to loop the rows inside the value field.i am using the c sharp programming

Comment: Please add [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [de-serialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) the response string into a concrete POCO or for now you can de-serialize into a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and project the `value` property's `url` property.

Here's an example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string response = @"
        {
          'odata.metadata': '',
          'value': [
            {
              'url': 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/5-93e1d09bdf66/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User'
            },
            {
              'url': 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/cb18b0aa-0ac6f51/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User'
            },
            {
              'url': 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/cf11211a06-ddee967505d8/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User'
            },
            {
              'url': 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/6a-bb9d-f08aee852c96/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User'
            },
            {
              'url': 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/62fce837ffb/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User'
            },
            {
              'url': 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/787cc75e-4726-89d/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User'
            },
            {
              'url': 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/26a2789b-2d/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User'
            },
            {
              'url': 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/6efcc6f2-333b-41e-6/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User'
            }
          ]
        }
    ";

    JObject graphResponseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response);
    IEnumerable<string> urls = graphResponseObject["value"]
                                .Select(x => x["url"].ToString());

    foreach (string url in urls)
        Console.WriteLine(url);

}
```

Outputting:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/5-93e1d09bdf66/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/cb18b0aa-0ac6f51/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/cf11211a06-ddee967505d8/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/6a-bb9d-f08aee852c96/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/62fce837ffb/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/787cc75e-4726-89d/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/26a2789b-2d/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/6efcc6f2-333b-41e-6/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
```

---

Here's your POCO to get you started:

```
public class GraphResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
    public string ODataMetaData { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public IEnumerable<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write wrapper class for that JSON

```
public class Value
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public string odata.metadata { get; set; }
    public IList<Value> value { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the JSON string to the class type `Example`

```
var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
var data = serializer.Deserialize<Example>(reader);
```

Comment: You mean deserialize

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mispelling

Answer (score 0):

Create A class

```
public class Values
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

then this code

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(JSONSTRING);
List<Values> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Values>>(jObject.GetValue("value").ToString());
foreach(var item in values)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(item.url);
 }
```